# How to add prefix or suffix to only One metric in a 2 metric bar chart

Tags: apache-superset, preset

I have a bar chart with 2 metrics (no: of Applications & sum of amount) and one X axis.I want to add a prefix as INR to only 1 metric (sum of Amount). The current version am using is V3.1.0 which has a bar chart customisation to prefix or suffix, however it applies on both the metrics.

I dont see a way to acheive the above requirement, please any help?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2VemY.png)

The current version am using is V3.1.0 which has a bar chart customisation to prefix or suffix, however it applies on both the metrics.